# Text box type text not typed and not shows in Mobile devices Google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net-mvc-4, textbox, geolocation

I have implemented one web application for hotels booking(www.weeklyhotels.com),In my application landing page destination search text box is there, in this text box I'm using Geo-location auto areas names fill.Im test test in desktop all browsers areal listing shows & working fine, but when i open in Android device in google chrome browser, and search any location text box text is not shows there , and same device if i open another browser it's working fine.

Comment: I tried it on Android 4.4.2 with chrome it works

Comment: #Vinod Louis thanks for giving replay , in some devices working some devices not working searching. Im searching in Samsung GT-19082 device version 4.2.2 , here search text is not appear. can you please check any another device an have any code.

Comment: Is there any one have solution regarding above issue , what can we say it's mobile side issue or else is there any java-script side issue i mean in application side.